# Blender for VFX

Tags: compositing-nodes, tracking, masking, effects

I wanted to know where can I began learning VFX in blender. I know that blender has a great compositing, camera tracking and masking etc. capabilities and I want to know how can I use them effectively to create effects like the ones in Infinity War and Harry Potter series. I know some YouTube channels have tutorials for this like [Kenan Proffitt](https://www.youtube.com/user/ChannelNews0) and [Darkfall](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCOUWVGNhcHEICE8AjR8up3g) but their tutorials teach how to achieve specific effects (like fire, smoke etc.) whereas I am looking for systematic tutorials from basics like the ones Blender Guru has for modelling. So it would be really helpful if someone guides me regarding this. Thanks.

Comment: Try looking into Moby Motion's camera tracking video. VFX has many components, such as simulations, destruction, modifiers, particles, camera tracking, and compositing. It might be more efficient to learn these things separately.

Comment: In reality, main industry 3d packages for feature film productions are still Houdini and Maya along with all other available tools depending on the department - 3DE and SynthEyes for tracking, Zbrush and 3d Coat for sculpting, Mari and Substance for texturing, Arnold and RenderMan for rendering and especially Nuke for compositing etc. as well as in-house developed tools like Gaffer. However, you can create feature film quality effects with Blender but there are a bunch of known limitations. TLDR; I'd suggest fxphd.com, also there are a lot good free tutorials on www.sidefx.com/tutorials/

Comment: Still valid: [Which would be the best VFX software for an absolute beginner?](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/14989/6685)

Comment: The best program for begginers to anything 3d is blender.  it's free, has more youtube tutorials than maya or 3dsmax, and is made by people who use it for real projects.